# Ask a phone to do one outgoing call

Tags: asterisk, sip, asteriskami

I am trying to get a solution to ask one my connected phone (SIP) to call an another one.

I can easily do this with an originate via one AMI request, but I have one problem :

- The display on my sip phone always show "incomming call".

There is one solution to get the display "outgoing call" on my sip phone ? Either with asterisk or in SIP protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Incoming call" is writed by your phone's firmware.

So you can only change to "outgoing call"(actualy it IS incoming) by rewriting call firmware or use phone which have that feature in firmware.

SIP standart have no any info about such feature.

Comment: That's was I suspect... Thanks for the response